# react native navigation - componentDidMount() fired twice

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am new to React Native. I am trying to build an app which has a `Splash` screen that would later navigate to `Login` screen if a user has not been authenticated or the `Main` screen if the user is authenticated. This is done using `this.props.navigation.navigate()`
The problem is that the `Splash` component would be mounted twice. I checked this by printing inside `componentDidMount()` of `Splash`. Because of this, the Login/Main screen enters twice, which looks very unpleasant. Is there any way to fix this? 
Also, I want to add some delay when the screen changes from `Splash` to `Login` or `Main` using `setTimeout()`. Anyway to go about doing this?
Here's my code:

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './src/reducers';

import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import LoginScreen from './src/components/Login/LoginScreen';
import Splash from './src/components/Login/Splash';
import Navigation from './src/components/Navigation/Navigation';
import { Font } from 'expo';
import {
  createStackNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fontLoaded: false,
      currentScreen: 'Splash',
    };
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({currentScreen: 'Login'}), 2000);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      'Quicksand': require('./assets/fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf'),
      'Quicksand-Medium': require('./assets/fonts/Quicksand-Medium.ttf'),
      'Quicksand-Bold': require('./assets/fonts/Quicksand-Bold.ttf'),
    });
    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }

  render() {
    const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      Splash: { screen: Splash },
      Main: { screen: Navigation },
      Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    })
    if (this.state.fontLoaded)
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <MainNavigator></MainNavigator>
        </Provider>
      )
    else return null;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Splash.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import bgImage from '../../../assets/images/login-background2.png';
import logo from '../../../assets/images/app-logo.png';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { checkAuth } from '../../actions/auth.actions';

class Splash extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions ={
    header: null
  }
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stillLoading: true,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.checkAuth();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.authState.isLoginPending)
      return (
        <ImageBackground source={bgImage} style={styles.backgroundContainer}>
              <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                  <Image source={logo} style={styles.logo}></Image>
                  <Text style={styles.logoText}> Welcome to HealthScout</Text>
              </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      );
    else if (this.props.authState.isLoginSuccess){
      setTimeout(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Main'));
      return null;
    }
    else{
      setTimeout(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login'));
      return null;
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    authState: state.authState
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    checkAuth: () => dispatch(checkAuth()),
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Splash);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: null,
    height: null,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  logoContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    width: 110,
    height: 149,
  },
  logoText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 40,
    fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
    opacity: 0.7,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: DidMount always gets triggered after a render. Make sure your `component` doesn't unnecessarily gets re-rendered to prevent the issue. Nothing wrong with the lifecycle here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Take out the `createStackNavigator` from `render`. 
It is better way wrapping screens above `App` class.

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Splash: { screen: Splash },
  Main: { screen: Navigation },
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
})

export default class App extends React.Component {
...
```

## Why?

`render` is run repeatedly depends on various conditions as changing state, props and so on.
And your code looks making multiple components with `createStackNavigation` in `render`. Take out :)

p.s If you want to wait loading fonts before show home screen, just change to home screen from splash screen after loaded fonts. Thus, the better way is loading fonts in `SplashScreen` and do what you want.

Comment: it is still fired twice even after took it out from render()

Comment: @xpcrtsAKARithisak did you fix this issue? I am having the same problem now.

Comment: @max can you try to remove <React.Strict> or similar like that in React Native root project, I think in index.js or app.js, and let's me know in comment again.

Comment: it was an issue with react navigation. to fix it I stored my tab navigator inside a stack navigator. not very elegant but it did work!